# Solving $n$th order determinant

Tags: determinant

I have a determinant of nth order that I am not able to convert into a triangular shape. I believe that this determinant is quite easy, but I can't find a way to fully convert one of the corners into zeros. My other idea was to use the Laplace principle, but that didn't work as well.
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 4 & 4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 4 & 4 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 4 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 4 \\       
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

If someone could present a detailed way of converting this determinant into a triangular shape, it would be much appreciated. 
In addition to that, maybe someone could give some tips for solving nth order determinant by converting it into a triangular shape, using the Laplace principle or any other more or less basic methods.

Comment: Use Laplace's formula for the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Laplace's formula for the first column, as mfl suggests, you arrive at the recurrence relation $D_n=4(D_{n-1}-D_{n-2})$ with $D_1=4$ and $D_2=12$.

The solution is $D_n=(n+1)2^n$.

Comment: Maybe you could explain this idea in depth ? 
I have been taught that the Laplace's principle is used when there are two or more rows/columns with zeros in corresponding places. Then those columns/rows can be removed and the minors of those elements could be calculated. Maybe this application of Laplace's theorem differs from yours.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. "Corresponding places"? Laplace expansion is when you write the determinant as a sum over determinants of minors. This can always be used.

Comment: Here's an example of how I was taught to use Laplace's principle : 
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 3 & 5 & -8  \\
        2 & 0 & 0 & 6  \\
        -1 & 2 & 5 & 4  \\
        -11 & 0 & 0 & 3  \\
      
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

Find minors of the removed rows and columns : 

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        2 & 6  \\
       -11 & 3  \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
*
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        3 & 5  \\
        2 & 5  \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
*
$(-1)^{11}$

Then we solve the second order determinants and get the answer : -360

Comment: Just look up "Laplace expansion" in the Wikipedia, man

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: doing row operations to get a diagonal matrix:
$$ R1\cdot (-\frac14)+R2\to R2; \ R2\cdot (-\frac13)+R3\to R3; \ etc$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}
        4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 4 & 4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 4 & 4 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 4 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 4 \\       
        \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
        4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \frac{12}{4} & 4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \frac{32}{12} & 4 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \frac{n\cdot 2^{n-1}}{(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}} & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \frac{(n+1)\cdot 2^n}{n\cdot 2^{n-1}} \\       
        \end{vmatrix}= \\ \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+1)\cdot 2^k}{k\cdot 2^{k-1}}=(n+1)\cdot 2^n.$$